# How to concatenate blocks of matrices to a single matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have 8x8 blocks of matrices. I want to concatenate all the blocks into a single matrix. Can anyone suggest me how to do it in matlab?

Comment: Do you mean you have 8x8=64 matrices you want to join together?

Comment: i have 1024 matrices of 8x8

Comment: Can you give an example with 4 2x2 matrices and how you want them put together?

Answer (score 3):

Lets look at a small example, suppose you have four 3x3 matrices:

```
A = rand(3);
B = rand(3);
C = rand(3);
D = rand(3);
```

Then you can concatenate them by doing:

```
M = [A B;C D]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using horzcat function in matlab. http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html                     see if this can help you